# Is there an npm package that compresses png images with transparency down as effectively as web tools like tinypng.com and compresspng.com?

Tags: image, optimization

I was completely amazed when these websites took my 4.53 mb spritesheet down to 1.51 mb. I looked for an npm package that could do something similar because it would be nice to do this from the command line with gulp. Every one I tried only shaved a few kb off. Am I just not finding it?

Comment: What compression options are you using? It's hard to say without more information, but my guess is that you are losslessly compressing your images and those sites are using lossy compression to get better results. Specifically, try and find an option to quantize your PNGs. Try the pngquant package

Comment: pngcrush didn't work, but pngquant DID! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pngquant did the job!

```
npm install --save imagemin-pngquant
```

And then the gulp task:

```
gulp.task('minify-img', function(){
    return imagemin(['./mobs/huge/*.png'], './mobs', {
        plugins: [
            imageminPngquant()
        ]
    }).then(function(){
        console.info("Images quant'd... is that a thing?!")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried imagemin-pngquant, but it made a little effect because of 1% compressed。If using Tinypng， the compressed ratio would reach 10% -- 90%